# Match the String with JSON String using Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex, json, pattern-matching

In my below code, `colData` stores `JSON String`. Sample example for colData-

> {"lv":[{"v":{"tenureSiteReg":null,"bghtItms":48,"pnlValue":105.478409,"byrSgmnt":2,"cstmrId":"814296998","slrRevRnk":-99.0,"soldItms":0,"slrSgmnt":6,"byrRevRnk":0.013,"mainAcct":78,"gmv":0.0,"cstmrRevRnk":0.021,"pnlRev":313.438843,"cstmrSgmnt":51,"gmb":4674.76,"totalVal":142.536293,"userId":493},"cn":42}],"lmd":20130}

Now I am trying to match `id` value with `userId` value in the above `JSON String`.
Meaning if `id` value is `493` then in the above JSON String `userId` value should also be `493`. And in the JSON String, it might be possible there are lot of `userId values` so all the `userId` values should be matching with `id`. If any of them doesn't matches then log the exception.

So I was trying something like this-

```
private static final Pattern USER_ID_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("userId:\\d+");

for (String str : colData) {
    Matcher matcher = USER_ID_PATTERN.matcher(str);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            if (!matcher.group().equals("userId:"+id))
                 System.out.println("LOG exception");

            }
}
```

But for the above JSON String, it is not going inside `while loop` also. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: *Is there anything I am missing?*  A JSON parser, perhaps?

Comment: @HotLicks, Can you provide me the example as well to achieve the above scenario?

Comment: Parse the JSON into a map.  In the map locate the "lv" array of maps.  Iterate through the array and locate the "v" element, which is another map.  Inside that map locate the "userId" element.

Comment: Where does the `id` value come from? Is it a separate string or is it supposed to be in the JSON?

Comment: Yes it's a separate string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Hot Lips noted in the comments, you should really use a JSON processor for this.

Here's a rudimentary example using the [Jackson JSON Processor](http://jackson.codehaus.org/). I assumed that `id` is a separate string since I didn't see it in the JSON.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"tenureSiteReg\":null,\"bghtItms\":48," +
                "\"pnlValue\":105.478409,\"byrSgmnt\":2,\"cstmrId\":\"814296998\",\"slrRevRnk\":-99.0," +
                "\"soldItms\":0,\"slrSgmnt\":6,\"byrRevRnk\":0.013,\"mainAcct\":78,\"gmv\":0.0," +
                "\"cstmrRevRnk\":0.021,\"pnlRev\":313.438843,\"cstmrSgmnt\":51,\"gmb\":4674.76," +
                "\"totalVal\":142.536293,\"userId\":493},\"cn\":42}],\"lmd\":20130}";
        String id = "493";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(json);
            List<JsonNode> userIds = rootNode.findValues("userId");         
            for (JsonNode node : userIds)
            {
                if (!id.equals(node.toString())) {
                    System.out.println("Log exception: id "+id+" != userId "+node);
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Congratulations! id "+id+" = userId "+node);
                }               
            }
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            System.out.println("JsonProcessingException: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Running this class produces:

```
Congratulations! id 493 = userId 493
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the help. I did exactly as it is. But I am getting error at `readTree` method saying that `The method readTree(JsonParser) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the arguments (String)`. May be I imported wrong jar file that's why? Can you please point me to right jar files if that is the case. I downloaded the jars from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjacksonjar.htm).

Comment: @Nevzz03 - I'm using version 1.9 and I'm using Maven to handle my dependencies. If you're using Maven, you can point to this repo: http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/jackson. Otherwise, you should be able to get all of the jars from http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload#Latest_stable_1.x_version. My project has the following 4 jars on the classpath: jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar; jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar; jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar; jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are simply missing the double quotation mark?

```
"userId:"493
```

try this for the pattern:

```
"userId\":(\\d+)"
```

Similarly you need the \" inside the matcher.group().equals(..)

Comment: Still the same thing. I tried using this- `public static final Pattern USER_ID_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("userId:\"(\\d+)");`. It's not going inside the while loop

Comment: oh my bad, the double quotation mark was in the wrong position relative to the colon.  here is the corrected pattern: try it again. "userId\":(\\d+)"

Comment: This pattern was verified as correct. If you want to use json parser instead it's your call.